# How can I change the value of a column in a table to have a certain default value?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column that is of a character type.

Can someone tell me how I configure a certain constant default value after the table has already been created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `n` as default value do

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT result_const DEFAULT 'n' FOR Result;
```